# In Python, how can you easily retrieve sorted items from a dictionary?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, list

Dictionaries unlike lists are not ordered (and do not have the 'sort' attribute). Therefore, you can not rely on getting the items in the same order when first added.

What is the easiest way to loop through a dictionary containing strings as the key value and retrieving them in ascending order by key?

For example, you had this:

```
d = {'b' : 'this is b', 'a': 'this is a' , 'c' : 'this is c'}
```

I want to print the associated values in the following sequence sorted by key:

```
this is a
this is b
this is c
```

Answer (score 17):

Do you mean that you need the values sorted by the value of the key?
In that case, this should do it:

```
for key in sorted(d):
    print d[key]
```

**EDIT:** changed to use sorted(d) instead of sorted(d.keys()), thanks [Eli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1694/eli-courtwright)!

Comment: You can actually just say "for key in sorted(d):" without having to say "d.keys()" since iterating over a dictionary just iterates over its keys.

Answer (score 16):

Or shorter,

```
for key, value in sorted(d.items()):
    print value
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "avoids the lookups"? does it result in better performance?

Comment: @Ray: yes, using "key, value" in the for loop avoids having to do the hash table lookup of d[key] for every item in the dictionary. I believe the above solution will be faster, but you'd have to measure it on your system and data set to be sure.

Comment: not really shorter. I personally find this harder to read/understand.

Answer (score 2):

This snippet will do it. If you're going to do it frequently, you might want to make a 'sortkeys' method to make it easier on the eyes.

```
keys = list(d.keys())
keys.sort()
for key in keys:
    print d[key]
```

Edit: [dF's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55193/2745495) is better -- I forgot all about `sorted()`.

Comment: Yes, but sorted isn't available in older python (pre 2.4), so this idiom is still useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can also sort a dictionary by value and control the sort order:

```
import operator

d = {'b' : 'this is 3', 'a': 'this is 2' , 'c' : 'this is 1'}

for key, value in sorted(d.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
    print key, " ", value
```

Output:
b   this is 3
a   this is 2
c   this is 1

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d = {'b' : 'this is b', 'a': 'this is a' , 'c' : 'this is c'}
>>> for k,v in sorted(d.items()):
...     print v, k
... 
this is a a
this is b b
this is c c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'b' : 'this is b', 'a': 'this is a' , 'c' : 'this is c'}
ks = d.keys()
ks.sort()
for k in ks:
    print "this is " + k
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in sorted(d):
  print d[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "sorted" instead of "ordered"? It seems your question aims at sorting a dictionary and not at ordering it. If you do mean "ordered", you can use an OrderedDict from the collections module. Those dictionaries remember the order in which the key/value pairs were entered:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
```

Reference information: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict